# Related Lists: Account to Account

Tags: account, related-list

is there a way to link Account records to each other via Related List (or something similar)? Here's what we're trying to achieve: my organization (a nonprofit) works with other organizations in coalitions, and we want to track which organizations are in which coalitions. For example, suppose there's a coalition called The Group, and organizations Cookie, Cake, and Donut make up the coalition. I'd want to see that reflected in the Cookie Account record, along with other coalitions they may be part of. And relatedly (ha), The Group Account record (or a more fitting record type) would list ALL Accounts that are part of the coalition.

I thought maybe Account hierarchies would work, but I don't think that's appropriate for what we're trying to do. Would love help if you have suggestions (or a solution)!

Comment: NonProfit Cloud (NPC) has a [Party Relationship Group concept](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/stakeholder-management-in-nonprofit-cloud/manage-organizations) that does what you're after. If you don't have NPC, one solution for a many to many account <-> group relationship is via a custom Group object + a [junction object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.relationships_manytomany.htm&type=5)